# Can't create app with UberRUSH API

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to create a new app using the UberRUSH API.
When I go to the developer dashboard and try to register a new app, when I select UberRUSH API I get a message saying,

> You need to register for UberRUSH before creating an app.

Which I already have.

Clicking the link to register for UberRUSH gives the following message,

> You are already signed in to your business account
>
> You already have a business account. If you would like to create a new
>   account, please log out first.

Am I missing a step? Or is there something broken in the flow?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like there may be an issue with your account. Do you mind sending an email to developer@uber.com with the email address that has this issue? We can debug from there.

Comment: My co-worker and I each tried signing up with different addresses and had the same result. Just sent an email to developer@uber.com

Comment: AND, just got a bounce back on my email: 
"We're writing to let you know that the group you tried to contact (developer) may not exist, or you may not have permission to post messages to the group. A few more details on why you weren't able to post:

 * You might have spelled or formatted the group name incorrectly.
 * The owner of the group may have removed this group.
 * You may need to join the group before receiving permission to post.
 * This group may not be open to posting."

Comment: Thanks, I was able to reproduce. Our engineers are working on a fix.

Comment: This is now resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update (7/15/2016): This was a bug. The sign-up flow should work correctly now.