# Unable to create app with UberRUSH website

Tags: uber-api

I came across exactly the same problem like here: [Can't create app with UberRUSH API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340887/cant-create-app-with-uberrush-api). Could you help me?

Best regards, 
Tomasz

Comment: There is already an accepted answer to that question.

Comment: That's true, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Do you get the exact error? Have you used a non business account? I would create another account for the rush business like uber@yourcompany.com

Comment: Unfortunately the same situation for a private account (gmail.com) and company one (sap.com). I end up with the message: "You need to register for UberRUSH before creating an app."

Comment: Can you confirm you signed up for that account at rush.uber.com?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it. I have a problem with two accounts connected with following e-mail addresses: tlempart[at]gmail[dot]com , tomasz.lempart[at]sap[dot]com .

Comment: It is working. I was able to create an app. Did you fix that, or something magical happened?

Comment: It turns out this was an issue on our side that is now resolved!

Comment: Thank's a lot @DustinWhittle!